Can't set tokenURI for ERC721 token despite safeMint having the parameter
in my Solidity smart contract (MyNFT.sol), I have the following function:
    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

My smart contract is copied from the [OpenZeppelin wizard][1], with the mintable, auto enumerable, and URI storage boxes checked in.
Using ethers.js, I first deployed the contract like this:
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import * as contract from "../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json" with { type: "json" };

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider("sepolia", API_KEY);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
  const MyNFT = new ethers.ContractFactory(contract.default.abi, contract.default.bytecode, signer);

  const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy(MY_WALLET_ADDRESS);

  await myNFT.waitForDeployment();
  const address = await myNFT.getAddress();
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", address);
}


Then, I tried to mint it like this:
import * as contract from "../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json" with { type: "json" };
const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider("sepolia", API_KEY);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const myNFTContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);

//pinata link:  "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSe4KMWG3MGuNdFXDEfJYSMpbfQq5Raxv63DQrKV3JXJF";
const tokenURI = "ipfs://QmQExDx5HpiHymDVNbDT7GCL7cWmLGDaMreZzSM3n7B1R9"
//myNFTContract.interface.fragments.filter(x => x.name == "safeMint").forEach(x => console.log(x.inputs));


const mintNFT = async () => {
  let nftTxn = await myNFTContract.safeMint(signer.address, tokenURI);
  await nftTxn.wait();
  console.log(`Minted NFT successfully! Txn: ${nftTxn.hash}`);
};

However, when I call mintNFT, I get this error:
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'fragment',
  info: {
    key: 'safeMint',
    args: [
      '0x06b0ED5338e36623b859081B0692F7dE33aF67E5',
      'ipfs://QmQExDx5HpiHymDVNbDT7GCL7cWmLGDaMreZzSM3n7B1R9'
    ]
  },
  shortMessage: 'no matching fragment'

I wrote this little snippet to check out the fragments of my compiled contract:
myNFTContract.interface.fragments.filter(x => x.name == "safeMint").forEach(x => console.log(x.inputs));
And it showed me this:
[
  ParamType {
    name: 'to',
    type: 'address',
    baseType: 'address',
    indexed: undefined,
    components: null,
    arrayLength: null,
    arrayChildren: null
  }
]

Why is there only one parameter for safeMint?  I've specified two.  I compiled using the latest version of Hardhat (npx hardhat compile`), and there aren't any errors anywhere.
Thanks for reading!
[1]: https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc721

How did you generate the ABI that you’re having in MyNFT.json? Make sure that the ABI is of the latest compiled contract.

@SYEDASADKAZMI thanks for the response - I used npx hardhat compile with hardhat v2.22.6 (the latest).  MyNFT.json is located in artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json.  I suspect it's a bug in hardhat

if you’re searching safeMint in your MyNFT.json, then is it having two objects in the inputs array?

@SYEDASADKAZMI turns out I was using an outdated smart contract for some reason which didn't have the _setTokenURI function call.  weird.  thanks for the help!
